# Can't specify database name during jdbc connection

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc

I'm using Spring MVC 4.3 to connect to a Miscorosft SQL Server with JDBC. My SQL Server have some databases, I'm trying to connect to TEST_DB one. But when I try to establish connection I receive this error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server principal "testuser" is not able to access the database "A_Source_Db" under the current security context.
```

`A_Source_Db` is the first db in alphabetical order, so I think I can't specify the db name to connect to.

I use Hibernate too and Spring Data. These are some files I think are useful

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.domain")
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@ComponentScan({"com.test", "com.test.domain.repository"})
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("mssql.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("mssql.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("mssql.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("mssql.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.test.domain");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
        properties.put(SHOW_SQL, true);
        return properties;
    }

}
```

This is my db.properties

```
mssql.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
mssql.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.100:1433;databaseName=TEST_DB
mssql.user=testuser
mssql.password=testPwd
```

Comment: You successfully connect to server but then your program/framework/i don't know what is trying to access another database. To find out the command that cause this error use SQL Server Profiler

Comment: Did you tried giving url like this?
mssql.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.100:1433/TEST_DB

Comment: How can it be that you connect under TEST user but the error you get is for TESTUSER?

Comment: @sepupic it's my mistake because i can't show real credentials

Comment: Ok, in any case your login was successfully logged on to the server. To its default database. If it was not so, you'd get the error "login failed for user testuser". But it was logged in. And THEN happens smth strange, because your testuser tries to access other databases. To find out how it can be launch prifiler and filter out the trace by your testuser login. It will show you all the commands that testuser tries to execute

Comment: Ok thank you all, I must wait for monday because I haven't direct access to SQL Server, so I must wait for db manager to come back to work. I'll let you know know

Comment: db owner changed my privileges... -_- sorry for the wasted time